# Reduce size of Google & Facebook php SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, google-analytics-api, google-php-sdk

I'm currently working on a plugin for wordpress, in which I have to use Google Analytics Reporting API and Facebook's Graph API.

Now everything is working fine with their respective php SDKs, the only problem is both are very large and not suitable for a plugin.

I'm only using Google Analytics Reporting API and oAuth from google sdk and some functions of Graph API.

What can I do to reduce size of the sdk?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you should attempt to do anything like that to begin with - chances are good you'll might eliminate files / methods that might only come into play in specific edge cases, and if your testing did neglect any of those, it might break things. You should not include any such external libraries directly into your plugin distribution - instead, properly declare them as external dependencies, and provide the plugin users with appropriate instructions / tools (like, say, a composer file) on how to install them themselves.

Comment: Okay, that would be better to just provide instructions of installing dependencies!